# EF CORE tries to insert modified entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, savechanges

the problem is when i get my entity from database and make some changes to its properties and want to save changes my modifications ef core tryes to not update but insert new entity into database. besides this entity with given pk alredy exists in database. also i am using repository pattern to manipulate access ta database.

here is my model strucrure and code

```
public class PurchaseRequestDocument
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public Document Document { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int RequestedForDepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department RequestedForDepartment { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project? Project { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PurchaseRequestDocumentItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class PurchaseRequestDocumentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PurchaseRequestDocument>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PurchaseRequestDocument> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(prd => prd.DocumentId);

            builder.Property(prd => prd.DocumentId)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Property(prd => prd.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(4000)
                .HasDefaultValue("");

            builder.HasOne(prd => prd.Document)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<PurchaseRequestDocument>(d => d.DocumentId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.HasOne(prd => prd.RequestedForDepartment)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(prd => prd.RequestedForDepartmentId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.HasOne(prd => prd.Project)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(prd => prd.ProjectId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

---

```
var purchaseRequestDocument = await _purchaseRequestDocumentRepository.GetDocumentWithItems(dto.DocumentId);

            if (purchaseRequestDocument is null)
                throw new NotFoundException(_localizer["DocumentNotFound"]);

            _mapper.Map(dto, purchaseRequestDocument);

            await _purchaseRequestDocumentRepository.InsertAsync(purchaseRequestDocument);

            return _mapper.Map<SavePRResponseDto>(purchaseRequestDocument);
```

Comment: There's no `InsertAsync` in EF Core, nor is one needed. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work that tracks *all* changes and persists *all* of them in a single database transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. If your `InsertAsync` calls `SaveChanges, then you have a critical bug that breaks EF Core's logic.

Comment: Assuming follows the antipattern of a CRUD class over DbContext, the wrapped DbContext already tracks `purchaseRequestDocument` and will detect any modifications to it. There's no need to call any other method to tell DbContext the object has changed. When SaveChanges is called , it will notice the object is Modified and generate an UPDATE statement for it. Specifically, DbContext will compare the current data with the original, find which properties have changed, and generate an UPDATE only for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you already said. You try to insert a already existing entry into your db.

Instead of

```
 await _purchaseRequestDocumentRepository.InsertAsync(purchaseRequestDocument);
```

try the `SaveChangesAsync` method of your dbContext